# Using pyhook to respond to key combination (not just single keystrokes)?

Tags: python, windows, automation, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been looking around but I can't find an example of how to use pyhook to respond to key **combinations** such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> whereas it is easy to find examples of how to respond to single keypresses such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd> separately.

BTW, I'm talking about Python 2.6 on Windows XP.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [GetKeyState](http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/pyhook.HookManager-module.html#GetKeyState) method from HookManager? I haven't tested the code but it should be something like this:

```
from pyHook import HookManager
from pyHook.HookManager import HookConstants

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    ctrl_pressed = HookManager.GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_CONTROL') >> 15)
    if ctrl_pressed and HookConstant.IDToName(event.keyId) == 'c': 
        # process ctrl-c
```

Here is [further documentation on GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You are missing a `)` on the fifth line.

Comment: And GetKeyState Doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I think it's been moved to `pyHook.GetKeyState`

Comment: What is that bitshifting going on? Is it important?

Comment: Actually I want to capture **Shift** + **PrintScreen**.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code to watch what pyHook returns:

```
import pyHook
import pygame

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print 'MessageName:',event.MessageName
    print 'Ascii:', repr(event.Ascii), repr(chr(event.Ascii))
    print 'Key:', repr(event.Key)
    print 'KeyID:', repr(event.KeyID)
    print 'ScanCode:', repr(event.ScanCode)
    print '---'

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()

# initialize pygame and start the game loop
pygame.init()
while True:
    pygame.event.pump()
```

using this, it appears that pyHook returns

```
c:      Ascii 99, KeyID 67,  ScanCode 46
ctrl:   Ascii 0,  KeyID 162, ScanCode 29
ctrl+c: Ascii 3,  KeyID 67,  ScanCode 46
```

(Python 2.7.1, Windows 7, pyHook 1.5.1)

Comment: yes, I've actually tried this code before but it seems to be processing each keystroke separately even though you are holding them down at the same time. I don't think there is a keycode for a combination of keystrokes.

Answer (score 7):

Actually Ctrl+C have it's own Ascii code (which is 3). Something like this works for me:

```
import pyHook,pythoncom

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 3:
        print "Hello, you've just pressed ctrl+c!"
```

Comment: While this answer is useful, I won't upvote it. This solves this particular situation, but what if I want to capture **Shift+PrintScreen**?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have luck with any of the other answers, so this is what I took to doing

```
class Keystroke_Watcher:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.on_key_down
        self.hm.KeyUp = self.on_key_up
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()
        self.keys_held = set()  # set of all keys currently being pressed

    def get_key_combo_code(self):
        # find some way of encoding the presses.
        return '+'.join([HookConstants.IDToName(key) for key in self.keys_held])

    def on_key_down(self, event):
        try:
            self.keys_held.add(event.KeyID)
        finally:
            return True

    def on_key_up(self, event):
        keycombo = self.get_key_combo_code()
        print(keycombo)
        try:
            # Do whatever you want with your keycombo here
        finally:
            self.keys_held.remove(event.KeyID)
            return True

    def shutdown(self):
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()
```