# Detecting key combinations using pyhook

Tags: python, keyboard, pyhook

I am currently using pyhook to capture keys using the hook manager's `KeyDown` event. This allows me to capture all single keys pressed on the keyboard.

However, I haven't been able to find a way to capture key combinations. For example, the event where `Ctrl`, `Alt` and `5` are all pressed at the same time, or `[` and `]` at the same time, and so on.

Is there a way to do this with pyhook that doesn't involve additional modules? For example, I've found [pyhk](http://www.schurpf.com/python/python-hotkey-module/) which seems like it would do the job, but would rather have as few dependencies as possible.

(This question is a *more generic version* (**not a duplicate**) of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581772/using-pyhook-to-respond-to-key-combination-not-just-single-keystrokes), for which the accepted answer only seems to deal with virtual key modifiers like `Ctrl`.)

Comment: This question is a more generic version of the one you linked to - see final paragraph of the question.

Comment: Not all keyboards are able to process every possible multi-key combination.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is quite old, however I do something like this using the window key-release event:

```
def _cb_event(self,widget,event,data=None):
    keyval = event.keyval
    keyname = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(keyval)
    mod = gtk.accelerator_get_label(keyval,event.state)
    keys=mod.upper()
    if keys=='SHIFT+F12':
        etc....
```

I did not use pyhook for this.