# How to capture Shift + PrintScreen with pyHook?

Tags: python, windows, pyhook

I was trying to capture <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> was captured in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4905495/939986).

Although the answer is outdated, but even if I fix the import, it doesn't works:

```
import pythoncom
from pyHook import HookManager, GetKeyState, HookConstants

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    ctrl_pressed = GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_CONTROL') >> 15)
    if ctrl_pressed and HookConstant.IDToName(event.keyId) == 'd':
        print("ctrl plus d was pressed at same time")

    return True

# create a hook manager
hm = HookManager()
# watch for all keyboard events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()
# wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

---

I wanted to capture PrintScreen key and open my Screenshot application, which I was able to do. Now I want to capture Shift + PrintScreen and open my application with some other config. How can I capture both key at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pyhook source code::HookManager.py](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/code/ci/master/tree/HookManager.py#l60) lists all defined key constants. In your case you'll have to check for the `Keystate` `VK_LSHIFT` in combination with the `event.KeyID` `VK_SNAPSHOT` (PrintScrn Key). Here's a working example:

```
import pythoncom
from pyHook import HookManager, GetKeyState, HookConstants

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    # in case you want to debug: uncomment next line
    # print repr(event), event.KeyID, HookConstants.IDToName(event.KeyID), event.ScanCode , event.Ascii, event.flags
    if GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_LSHIFT')) and event.KeyID == HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_SNAPSHOT'):
        print("shift + snapshot pressed")
    elif GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_CONTROL')) and HookConstants.IDToName(event.KeyID) == 'D':
        print("ctrl + d pressed")
    return True

# create a hook manager
hm = HookManager()
# watch for all mouse events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()
# wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

If you want to also bind it to the right-shift-key you'll have to check for the `VK_RSHIFT` keystate.

```
if (GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_LSHIFT')) or GetKeyState(HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_RSHIFT'))) and event.KeyID == HookConstants.VKeyToID('VK_SNAPSHOT'):
```

Comment: Well I got Shift+PrintScreen working, I can't capture Ctrl+D.

Comment: @SantoshKumar I've updated the code to properly capture ctrl+d.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @tintin. There no active development in this pyHook field so finding answers are so painful. Thanks for the help. Take extra 50 reputation as a gift. ;) How can I connect with you?

Comment: you're welcome. I'll be around, feel free to ask questions or ping me if you feel like your're hitting a dead end.